# Using the input parameters from stored parameters as variables inside where clause MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mysql-variables

I have a simple mysql table:

```
CREATE TABLE  `cont` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Meeting_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `member_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `cont_prod` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `type_of` varchar(100),
  `ord_qty` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ;
```

I am trying to dynamically transpose rows to columns following this example [enter link description here](https://ubiq.co/database-blog/transpose-rows-columns-dynamically-mysql/)

1. In side the **SELECT STATEMENT** when I use the input parameters inside **WHERE** clause it is giving me error column not found.
2. I tried to declare the variable as :

   SET @v1 = c_prod;
   SET @v2 = s_date;

and teh in the where clause:

```
WHERE cont_prod = @v1 AND start_date = @v2
```

it is still not working

How can I define the input parameter variable inside the WHERE clause?

Any help would be highly apprecuited.

```
 BEGIN
         SET @sql = NULL;
    SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
          'max(case when type_of = '',
          type_of,
          '' then ord_qty end) ',
          type_of
        )
      ) INTO @sql
    FROM
      cont
      where cont_prod = c_prod AND start_date = s_date;
    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT product_id,member_name,start_date,cont_prod, ', @sql, ' 
                      FROM cont WHERE cont_prod = c_prod AND start_date = s_date
                       GROUP BY member_name,cont_prod,start_date');
    
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE st......
```

Comment: `''` should be `'''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `?` to specify parameters in the prepared statement, and pass the parameters on the `EXECUTE` line.

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT product_id,member_name,start_date,cont_prod, ', @sql, ' 
            FROM cont WHERE cont_prod = ? AND start_date = ?
            GROUP BY member_name,cont_prod,start_date');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt USING c_prod, s_date;
```

Comment: thank you. Appreciate your help!!  it was giving the error on Excute stmt line. Si have to declare variables an duse them lik: EXECUTE stmt USING '@v1', '@v2';